# About to take an Emirates flight to Philippines: Can I carry medicine with prescription (from my mom, she's a doctor) just in case I need it?

Tags: health, philippines, dxb, emirates

Please take into account I am not American and do not live in USA.

My mom is a doctor and she wants to give me some medicine, for example, antibiotics, (all in solid form) and their prescription just in case of need.

Is this allowed and if not what is the worst that can happen to me?

Does a layover in Dubai affect this situation?

Comment: Why the US reference? And if you're in, or transiting the US, do any of the meds contain narcotics? Also, are the prescriptions accompanied by translations into the relevant language for the country/countries you'll enter?

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that a family member writing a prescription for you, especially without a good medical reason, is going to raise a red flag. If the prescription was for a drug that had street value, say pain killers rather than antibiotics, that's going to be another red flag.

Comment: @pnuts: all solid.

Comment: @Dorothy: I will not be transiting the US, not even travelling to there. No, no prescriptions accompanied by translations but I can translate those prescriptions if it is necessary.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Buy my mom has different surname (I got the surname from my father).

Comment: The [Philippine Consulate General in Chicago](http://www.chicagopcg.com/news.html#drugs) offers this about bringing in prescriptions: _Visitors taking prescription drugs (tables and ampoules) should bring a letter from their physician stating the condition for which they are receiving treatment and the dosage. The amount of drugs brought into the country should also be sufficient for the duration of the visit._ English is the second language of the country, btw, should the statement need to be translated.

Comment: @Dorothy: Does landover in Dubai affect this situation?

Comment: If you're transiting, and staying airside, it's not an issue, nor is it one should you go through security, according to the [UAE London Embassy](http://www.uae-embassy.ae/Embassies/uk/Content/678). In any case, btw, you don't want to include any medication that has pseudoephedrine as an ingredient.

Comment: @Dorothy: Thanks for answering. last question: Does having medications stored NOT in bag in hand change anything?

Comment: Not at all, but it is advisable to put all meds in your carry-on baggage.

Comment: Where is your point of departure?

Answer (score 1):

There are no issues for you in Dubai; because you will not pass customs or immigration while in transit.

There are no exit controls in the US.

However, when you arrive at your final destination - you may need to show a prescription and the drugs (ideally, they should be in their commercial packaging) to customs.

As long as the drugs are of a reasonable quantity for the time you will be there, and are not restricted (sometimes, drugs that are perfectly legal in one country, may be illegal in others - this is especially true with painkillers and other drugs that contain narcotics) and you have a prescription, you will not face any issues.